# How to put symbol after each 3 numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling with putting a dot after each 3 numbers in JavaScript.

I know that it should be done using regex and I should use join method? But can someone please tell me how to implement that?

My idea for now is to do like that:

```js
let num=12312;
let res=num.replace(/(.{3}/g,".");
console.log(res);
```

But that's not working.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add your best attempt as a runnable snippet reproducing your problem. Also try to be more precise on **exactly when** should **exactly what** happen.

Comment: Is this just fizzbuzz? It seems like fizzbuzz

Comment: Are you trying to present the number with French style thousand separators?

Comment: @Quentin Then `123.456.78` wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @connexo — Good point, it would be every third from the right, not the left then, wouldn't it?

Answer (score -2):

You can use toLocaleString to add comma after 3 number.

```js
var x = 100000000;
console.log(x.toLocaleString('EN-US'))
```

Comment: Just curious, how did you manage post an answer to a closed question after it was closed?

Comment: @vanowm https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed

Comment: Try that with `1000` instead of `100000000`. Your code puts the character **before** every third character from the **right**, not after every third character from the left. Also you picked a US locale so its the wrong character. It only works in your example because the number of digits in the number is divisible by three.

Comment: @vanowm I was typing the answer. I didn't know It's closed.